# Set global options for \inputminted

Tags: minted

I am using the `minted` package to highlight source code.

How can I set the options parameter globally for `\inputminted`? I want to do this because I have a lot of php code files that I will include in my document and I do not want to lose time to specify the options each time.

I have tried to define the default values for mint with the command:

```
\newmint{php}{
 %options
 }
```

and after that tried:

```
....
\inputminted{php}{foo.php}
....
```

and after compile the settings that I have done with `\newmint` are ignored.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

L.E: This is what i got until now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{article}
%php syntax highlight
\userpackage[chapter]{minted}
\definecolor{mintedbackground}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newmint{php}{
bgcolor=mintedbackground,
fontfamily=tt,
linenos=true,
numberblanklines=true,
numbersep=12pt,
numbersep=5pt,
gobble=0,
frame=leftline,
framerule=0.4pt,
framesep=2mm,
funcnamehighlighting=true,
tabsize=4,
obeytabs=false,
mathescape=false
samepage=false, %with this setting you can force the list to appear on the same page
showspaces=false,
showtabs =false,
texcl=false,
}

\begin{document}
     \inputmined{php}{foo.php}
\end{document}
% The settings for php are ignored.
```

L.E: I have found in the documentation of minted that i can use `\newmintedfile` Finally, define a new language-specific alias for `\inputminted`.

The problem is that I do not understand from the example in doc how can I define the global settings.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Corentin Hello, what have i don wrong?

Comment: @Starlays It's difficult to say, without some code for making a comparison.

Comment: @egreg what do you mean without some code for making comparison? that is what i have done in my document, defined a `\newmint{code}{options} and tried to use that code that i have defined but the settings are ignored.

Comment: @Starlays egreg is asking you for a [`minimal working example`](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html); a minimal, yet complete document showing the relevant settings and illustrating the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina i have updated my post, added a minimal not working example.

Comment: @Starlays This is not yet MWE since you have not included even a snippet of your `foo.php` file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Some fixes

Well, you were on the right track. You just change `\newmint` into `\newmintedfile` and, after fixing some settings in your MWE, it will compile with the `-shell-escape` option passed to `pdflatex`.

The following were the fixes.

1. There is no `openright` option for `article` class, and hence no `chapter` option for `minted` as this seems like your settings in your original `report` file
2. There was a typo in `\inputmined`. It should be `\inputminted`.

### Explanation of `\newmintedfile`

The syntax is `\newmintedfile[<alias>]{<language>}{<external file>}`.

The usage is the same as that of `\newmint`. If you have explicitly specified its alias, say `phpcode` then you can use `\phpcode{foo.php}`, otherwise, `file` is appended to the language name, in this case you write `\phpfile{foo.php}`. The documentation was not so good at explaining this but you can find the parallelism with the `\newmint` command and their definitions.

### The codes

Here is the file `foo.php` that I used:

```php
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

And here is the `foobar.php` file:

```php
<?php
//This is a PHP comment line

/*
This is
a PHP comment
block
*/
?>
```

And finally the LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}
%php syntax highlight
\usepackage[section]{minted}
\definecolor{mintedbackground}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\newmintedfile[phpcode]{php}{
bgcolor=mintedbackground,
fontfamily=tt,
linenos=true,
numberblanklines=true,
numbersep=5pt,
gobble=0,
frame=leftline,
framerule=0.4pt,
framesep=2mm,
funcnamehighlighting=true,
tabsize=4,
obeytabs=false,
mathescape=false
samepage=false, %with this setting you can force the list to appear on the same page
showspaces=false,
showtabs =false,
texcl=false,
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\phpcode{foo.php}

\kant[1]

\phpcode{foobar.php}

\end{document}
```

### The output

And here is the output

[image]

Comment: One addition to [@hpesoj626's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103191/95441), if there are too long lines, you may need to add `breaklines` option to break the lines.