# TeXworks: Minted cannot find file or directory

Tags: minted, texworks, python, pygments

I cannot get minted running with TeXworks on Windows 10 and I dont know why...

This is my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[h!]
    \begin{minted}{Python}
        def hello_world():
            print("Hello floating world!")
    \end{minted}
    \inputminted{pascal}{screentime/screentime.pas} 
    \caption{Floating listing.}
    \label{lst:hello}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Compile error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/schodmi/Desktop/A01/Lesson-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics
.cfg)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.d
ef)))
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/minted\minted.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.s
ty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys
.sty))
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fvextra\fvextra.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
) (C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/upquote\upquote.sty
) (C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lineno\lineno.sty))
 (C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform
.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcm
ds.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr
.sty)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile
.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.s
ty))
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty)
) (C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty

(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex
)) (C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/framed\framed.sty)
 (C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty))
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cf
g))
C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\mik79764\_src>set  /p x=C:\Users\schodmi\Miniconda3\Scripts\pygmentize.exe 0<nul: 1>>Lesson-1.aex 

C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\mik79764\_src>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>Lesson-1.aex 

C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\mik79764\_src>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>Lesson-1.aex 

(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-p
dftex.def)
No file Lesson-1.aux.

(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.
mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf
-base.sty
(C:\Users\schodmi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys
.cfg)) [1{C:/Users/schodmi/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(_minted-Lesson-1/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
(_minted-Lesson-1/default.pygstyle)
(_minted-Lesson-1/30A1976BD221E0E570D0694297709B14BEF32A50D0526707C76F4235AAD6E
FD1.pygtex)Error: cannot read infile: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'screentime/screentime.pas'


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34 ...tminted{pascal}{screentime/screentime.pas}
                                                  
?
```

I have python 3.9.5 installed (Miniconda), i have pygmentize in "C:\Users\schodmi\Miniconda3\Scripts" and added it to my environment variables.

It seems that the .pyg files are stored in %AppData%/../Temp and cannot be found by TeXworks but I did not find any help on this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as I can see file `screentime/screentime.pas` can not be found. Where have you stored it? In that directory? Is that directory a subdirectory to the directory you have your TeX code?

Comment: It is in the same directory. In the directory where my .tex file is is a folder named screentime which contains a file screentime.pas Edit: maybe pygmentize cannot find the file? But i dont even know where to put it and it wouldnt be very practical if i had to copy it somewhere else

Comment: may be look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103141/set-global-options-for-inputminted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi don't You wonna try this one?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
breakatwhitespace=false,         
breaklines=true,                 
captionpos=b,                    
keepspaces=true,                 
numbers=left,                    
numbersep=5pt,                  
showspaces=false,                
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,                  
tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=Python,caption={My listing},label={lst:1}]{4.py}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TeXworks does not look into your own environments variables. When TeX is launched by TeXworks, it only knows a limited set of locations where to search for shell commands. In particular, TeX has no idea where to look for pygment.

An [issue](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/946) has been filled on that matter.

In the meanwhile, the solution on OS X is to launch TeXworks from the terminal instead of the desktop. There is certainly something equivalent on Windows.